# Other possible Docker log locations?

Tags: docker, logging, containers, vagrant

Every source I read is saying the log locations are here:

`/var/lib/docker/containers/{container-id}/{container-id}-json.log.`

But when I check mine, all I see is `/var/lib/docker/containers/{container-id}/` and when I `ls` that, it shows:

```
checkpoints  
config.v2.json  
hostconfig.json  
hostname  
hosts  
resolv.conf  
resolv.conf.hash  
secrets  
shm
```

No logs at all.

What are other possible log locations of the containers?

Btw, host is Vagrant CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

Rhetorical question: why would you need to know that?

You can access a container's logs by calling `docker container logs <container_id>`, and `docker-compose logs <service>` in compose. These commands dump the contents of the logs to stdout where you can process them using normal pipes. The containers themselves also send their logs (by default) to stdout, so you can pipe them directly to a log-shipping service or anything else that takes your fancy.

The location of the log history files is an implementation detail that changes across platforms and is configurable per daemon and is even configurable per container. Using the CLI (or REST API) is the most platform-independent way to access the logs and it saves you having to find them.

Comment: Yes I am usually using `docker logs` but for this use case I am trying to configure Filebeat as container and it needs the log location source.

Comment: AFAIK: filebeat can be configured to read directly from the container rather than from a path: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-docker.html

Comment: Btw: fluentbit seems easier -- just set fluentbit as each container's logdriver. Then you don't have to worry about running out of diskspace while logging json (by default) to your local drive.

Comment: I decided to just reinstall docker engine and it fixed the issue. The json logs now appears.

Answer (score 0):

For those who care:

I may be running an old docker engine which did not use `json-file` logging driver as default. I tried changing the default driver to `json-file` but that resulted to cascading errors that needed fixing, one after another.

So I decided to F it and completely reinstall the docker engine and rebuild the images. Guess what, the `/var/lib/docker/containers/{container-id}/{container-id}-json.log.` files magically appeared.

Note: You may need to rebuild all images that you want to use this logging format.